# mosquitto+mqtt.js got "Connection refused: Not authorized"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I built mosquitto on CentOS7 and a node.js client based on [mqtt.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js),installing with

```
yum install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```

The local test

```
> mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t test

> mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t test -m "hello world"
```

works fine, but when I ran:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.1.70')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

I got  **Error: Connection refused: Not authorized**

The *mosquitto.conf* is like:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
allow_anonymous true
```

and I use *systemctl restart mosquitto* to restart it several time, which doesn't help. The firewall is down and log file stays empty.
A screenshot on status:
[image]

Can anyone help please?

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that the mosquitto service is somehow broken as the status shows `Active: active (exited)`.
I use `mosquitto -p 1884 -v` cmd to run another mosquitto process on port 1884, it works fine. Then I try to reload the conf using 
`> /etc/init.d/mosquitto reload`. It gives me

Reloading mosquitto configuration (via systemctl):  Job for mosquitto.service invalid.
                                                           [FAILED]

So there IS something wrong with mosquitto service.
Not a final solution but I manage to fix this by remove-reboot-install process, the status went green as follow:

[image: Correct mosquitto status]

**SOLUTION**

I managed to find out the reason it doesn't work. I've installed rabbitmq on my server, it uses its "rabbitmq_mqtt" which consumes port 1883. Reassigning a port will solve this problem.

Comment: What is in the mosquitto logs when the NodeJS client tries to connect?

Comment: As I said..the werid thing is that the logs are empty ,  not sure if the log function was not able to run.

Comment: Stop mosquitto and run it manually with just `-v` on the cmd line

Comment: well if I use mosquitto -v to start another mosquitto process on port 1884, everything works fine.But not that mosquitto service,it still shows Not authorized on port 1883.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find out the reason. I've installed rabbitmq on my server, it uses its "rabbitmq_mqtt" which consumes port 1883. Reassigning a port will solve this problem. The problem is simple, but yeah, the CLI should have given me more information.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the authorize information to mqtt connect method.Just like this.

```js
var client=mqtt.connect("ws://192.168.1.1", {
            username: "yourUsername",
            password: "yourPassword"
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for tips on asking good and clear questions.

Comment: But I set anonymous true, it should allow anonymous connection.

Answer (score -1):

Add the Authorization details for the client to connect

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.1.70', {
                              username: '<username>', 
                              password: '<password>'
              });

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```